# file command output for a non-ASCII text file in AIX and Linux

Tags: text, file-command

I am getting different output while using `file` command in AIX vs Linux.

File contents :

```
D|P_APAC_PH_PHINGTF00240_20150731031225|APAC|PH|NN (L) SPEK DYWIDENDOWYCH RYNKÓW WSCHODZCYCH||4|20130308|PHN|PHN|1145050.06|1145050.06|301893.026||||ING|ING|PHINGTF00240|ISIN|||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

`file` output:

```
LINUX : ISO-8859 text
AIX : ascii text
```

I can see one accented letter O in the file. Is it the reason for the different output?

Comment: Different implementation; the [spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/file.html#tag_20_46_01) doesn't dictate that level

Answer (score 3):

The `Ó` is probably why `file` on your Linux box is saying `ISO-8859 text`, but the reason why the `file` output is **different** is because your Linux box and your AIX box have different magic databases for `file` to work with.

AIX almost certainly has an ancient, obsolete magic db.  Linux machines tend to have reasonably up-to-date ones with identifier sequences for many more kinds of files.

Comment: Thanks....Can u specify the exact entry which i have to check in /etc/magic file

Comment: @GAURAVMAHAJAN You should be using utf-8 across all your systems and forget about "character sets".

Comment: The difference may be simply that `file` on Linux looks at a bigger part of the file than on AIX. `file` **guesses** the file format based on the content, it doesn't have access to any metadata that would tell it the file encoding, it's possible that the AIX version looks at a smaller part of the file so it only sees the ASCII characters at the beginning. @GAURAVMAHAJAN

Comment: you can test @Gilles theory by creating a much smaller text file, with `Ó` in the first few characters and then running `file` on that.

Comment: @BinaryZebra - does AIX, and its versions of standard tools, support UTF-8?

Comment: They certainly should. Shame on them if they don't. @cas